# In CI/CD piplines, how do you run a portion of the build process using an interval?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, travis-ci, gitlab-ci

Assume I'm using a GitLab pipeline and there is a build process that gets everything ready for production. There is a 3rd party database that needs to be downloaded, e.g. a MaxMind Geo database. I don't want to strain their servers every time we run a build, so I'd want to only download the latest database once a month.

What tactics can I use to save a "last run" date, check it, and take action to download the DB if the last run date is more than a month ago?

Answer (score 0):

i would use the [`cache`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache) option in the gitlab-ci.yml

Create a file named "update_date" once you update the db then cache it.
In the logic.py (python is just an example, write it however you'd like), check the file exists and date is not over 30 days ago, in any other case update the DB

```
db_update:
  script:
    - logic.py
  cache:
    paths:
      - ./update_date
```